# Using newer version of tikz-cd for arXiv submissions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just realized that [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) has an older version of [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). Therefore, using the standard package of `tikz-cd` and to submit a paper to arxiv seems impossible, if one requires the newer version of `tikz-cd` in the written code.

A straigtforward question is, how to alleviate this problem? Is it possible to avoid this package to be used by arXiv but rather to use it inside the LaTeX code?

A similar question also appears [here](http://www.faqssys.info/tikz-cd-equal-and-arxiv/) but I don't have equal but I have rather other code parts for example `gathered` or `\makebox` in the code.

Comment: Providing the license permits it, rename the file and upload the renamed file with your code.

Comment: @Johannes_B excuse me what which licence? I had already ticked this licence "arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article "

Comment: The license of the Tikz Library, or tikz if the package doesn't come with its own license.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the comments but I am not able to make use of them. I have the newer version of miktex and I can compile it without any problem. I dont have any idea about the licenses or how I can add them to my document? or should I add a licence to my document? My tex knowledge is very basic.

Comment: Is creating an image an including it with `\includegraphics` an option?

Comment: @cfr yes I think it may be an option. Another option is to create the graph here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215770/arranging-the-arrows-in-align-environment  without using tikz-cd. The only problem is about the brackets, which is probably not the easiest without tikz-cd.

Comment: This is what externalisation is designed for.  However, there are issues using externalisation with tikz-cd.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171931/86 for details and a (hacky) solution.

Answer (score 7):

As of this writing, the arxiv still uses texlive 2011.  For me, at least, the only viable option is to take @cfr's suggestion, and make the diagram in a standalone document, then include it back in the original with `\includegraphics`.  Details of the following might not be the best way to do it, but it works for me.  Here's the standalone `commutative-diagram.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
% any other macros or packages that might affect the diagram
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    P \arrow[d, "a"] \arrow[rd, "b"]
    & \\
    S^3 \arrow[r, "c"] & S^2
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[Note that I think the equation environment is not strictly necessary, but I like to keep it, in case I do something weird.]  I process that on its own with `pdflatex`.  Then in the main document, I just have

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:commutative-diagram}
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{commutative-diagram}}
\end{equation}
```

That `\raisebox` part makes sure the label is aligned with the center, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7222/5741).

It's an ugly and annoying solution, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

The package is under the free [GNU license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/). So you are golden on that side.

You need to locate the file `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`, rename it to `tikzlibrarySeyhmus.code.tex` and load it in your document. Of course you need to upload the renamed file as well.

Instead of loading `tikz-cd` do the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}[2013/12/13]
\usetikzlibrary{Seyhmus}
```

But since [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) needs [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) version 3 to run, and arXiv is still with version 2.1, this is bound to fail. Depending on the arXiv workflow, this can also break the stuff of other authors. So be careful.

Comment: @svend Wow, so many typos. Thanks :-)

Comment: where is that file? and I think I will skip \usepackage{tikz-cd} right?

Comment: You haven't revealed anything about your system, so »Don't know« is the only thing i can respond to that. I bet your favourite file manager (like microsoft explorer) can search for the file.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215770/arranging-the-arrows-in-align-environment  the unaccepted answer here uses tikz-cd and this is the code part which creates me a problem when I upload.

Comment: I had a typo in the name above, please have a look. What kind of error are you getting? I don't have an old version of pgf around, so i cannot test if the code would work with 2.1 Please uncomment the braket with the date while loading tikz and try if it runs.

Comment: I did as you said and without tikz-cd I was able to compile on my machine. Then I tried to upload the document to arxiv once again and here is the error: LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 11, version
`2013/12/13' of package tikz,
but only version
`2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)'
is available.

Comment: I understood that typo and corrected it already..

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören This is exactly what Johannes_B told you would happen. I think, however, that Johannes_B probably meant to suggest commenting the bracket with the date to see if it works. However, if you really need the newer version because of underlying changes in the TiKZ code, you will be out of luck. That is, if the newer library really ***needs*** that version of TiKZ (it means what it says), then it is not going to work with an older version of TiKZ. Frankly, it will be surprising if it works with a version from 2010 - a ***lot*** has changed.

Comment: @cfr I think if it is a package is updated, then this update can be used in the code without referring it, just copy paste the code part whereever it is in the newer version. But Of course I dont know where it is and how it is organized. BTW I havent tried what you said yet. I will go it then today and write back here about what happened.

Comment: The point is that the code you've pasted checks for a sufficiently recent version of TiKZ and refuses to continue if it does not find it. If it doesn't need the newer version really, commenting the check will allow it to succeed. But if it really needs the newer version, obviously that won't work.

Answer (score -1):

The following variation of the solution by Mike finally worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/ -type f -exec cp {} pgftikz/ \;
```

One also needs:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
```

Comment: You say "one also needs `tikz-cd.sty`" and then supply a lengthy path for `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`. Where does the former reside then?