# Arranging the arrows in align environment without using tikz-cd

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I have previously asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215770/arranging-the-arrows-in-align-environment). To be self explanatory I would like to state it here once again:

I have the following code and I dont know how to align the two horizontal `\Longleftrightarrow`s vertically higher than they are now. Ideally they need to be only vertically moved a bit up so that one of them is vertically between `c_2` and `c_1` and the other needs to be between `c_3` and `c_4`.

```
\begin{align}
a(y)&=1-a(-y)\nonumber\\
&\Uparrow \nonumber\\
m_u=1/m_l \quad\quad\,\, c_2&=c_3 \quad\quad\,\,  \lambda_0=\lambda_1\nonumber\\
t_u=-t_l\Longleftrightarrow c_1&=c_4 \Longleftrightarrow \mu_0=\mu_1 \nonumber\\
&\Updownarrow \nonumber\\
f_1(y)&=f_0(-y)
\end{align}
```

Now I need however, brackets. Because without brackets it might mean different. I received an two very good answers for this question and one is even with brackets BUT it uses tikz-cd and arxiv doesnt accept it. See this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223764/using-newer-version-of-tikz-cd-for-arxiv-submissions). Therefore, I need to have the graph with brackets. Is there any way to do it without using tikz-cd and tikz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with the extensions to the cases environment from `mathtools` and a few adjustments with the `makebox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}%{2}
a(y)& =1-a(-y)\nonumber\\
& \makebox*{${}={}$}{$ \Uparrow $} \nonumber\\
\begin{rcases}\begin{cases} m_u =1/m_l \\t_u =-t_l \end{cases}\hskip-1.18em\end{rcases}\Longleftrightarrow\begin{cases} c_2\\c_1\end{cases}\hskip-1.18em & \begin{rcases} = c_3\\ = c_4 \end{rcases}
\Longleftrightarrow\begin{rcases}\begin{cases}\lambda_0=\lambda_1\\
 \mu_0=\mu_1\end{cases}\hskip-1.18em\end{rcases} \nonumber\\
&\makebox*{${}={}$} {$\Updownarrow$} \nonumber\\
f_1(y)& =f_0(-y)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Missing brackets from the left and right can be corrected?

Comment: @Seyhmus Güngören: See my updated answer.

Comment: do you have any idea why the bracket size of the very left "cases" environment is smaller than the other two?

Comment: I hadn't paid attention to this point. It comes from the order of the nestìng of the `cases/rcases` environments. It's fixed. Is is all right now?

Comment: I think it is good enough. Do you have any idea why tikz seems still better than this? By the way this has also some nicer parts like the equations are aligned and that the equation number is just below everything. I think tikz has only nicer arrows, I would say.

Comment: I have the document file \documentclass[12pt,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran} and when I use this, one of the brackets is becoming smaller! I am really schocked. Please let me know if you have any idea to resolve this. My final idea is that this answer is nicer and I want to use it but I need it in both of my documents. In the other document everything is fine.

Comment: I don't really know. I used the default arrows from amsmath. actually I don't like so much default tikz-cd arrows, and I usually prefer to use the `psmatrix` environment from pstricks for commutative diagrams, as I feel I have more control on a lot of details, with a LaTeX-like syntax.

Comment: I changed my code: it was enough to replace the `cases` environment with `cases*`. In addition, I don't have to make any horizontal adjustment any more, so the code is simpler. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. now it is free of problems and seems very nice.

Answer (score 2):

The result seems adequate; on the other hand, I think I'd have a hard time in trying to understand what the diagram means. But the document is yours. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&\makebox[0pt]{$\displaystyle a(y)=1-a(-y)$} \\[1ex]
&&\Uparrow \\
\left\{
  \!\begin{aligned}
  m_u&=1/m_l\\
  t_u&=-t_l
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
&
\Longleftrightarrow
&
\!\begin{aligned}
  c_2&=c_3 \\
  c_1&=c_4
\end{aligned}
&
\Longleftrightarrow
&
\left\{
  \!\begin{aligned}
  \lambda_0&=\lambda_1 \\
  \mu_0&=\mu_1
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\\
&&\Updownarrow \\[1ex]
&&\makebox[0pt]{$\displaystyle f_1(y)=f_0(-y)$}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thats cool!! thx!!

Comment: I just compared with the tikz-cd output. The \Longleftrightarrow s seem uglier than the ones obtained with tikz-cd. Why is it so?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Because that's how they're printed.

Comment: ohh I understood why. It is because of array environment. The equations in brackets are treated as another column and therefore the space is much more and to fill this space the arrows are arranged automathically by tex.